# Softlayer REST API: route a globalip fails

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use below REST APIs to route a global ip to a target, the response code is 200, but the response body is error, I'm not sure what is going on here.

2016/11/21 15:19:40 [DEBUG] Path:  https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/52703/route.json

2016/11/21 15:19:40 [DEBUG] Parameters:  {"parameters":["169.55.61.222"]}

2016/11/21 15:19:42 [DEBUG] Response:  {"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status code 200 and the response body with an "Internal Error" is a bug. It is already reported.

Nevertheless, in order to successfully apply the **route** method with a global IP, such as "169.55.61.222" first you need to assign an address to it, in other words, the **destinationIpAddressId** attribute should not be null.